# Android How can I change image on gridview by position?

Tags: android, gridview, android-imageview, puzzle

I have a slide puzzle game.

I want to change image on **`GridView`** by position(id).

How could I do that?

Comment: have you done any code?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
     gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
{
    // You can get position of item or imageView and again you can set new image  
   //  by setBackGround() by getting this position

}
 });
```

Comment: I want something like this : grid.setBitmapImage(position, bitmap)